# table of contents creation in latex

Tags: table-of-contents

I have problems with creating the table of contents in LATEX. Could anyone help me

[image]

Instead of 2 then 2.1 and 2.2, the table turns into this order

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: As you have shown no code, how are we to guess what commands you have put in the document to generate that fragment of an image? please add a small complete document that produces the numbers that you show as text in a code block, so people can debug.

Comment: also your second image is missing, can you re-submit it

Comment: That is not the normal ToC output. Please show what you have done to get it.